# Regex: only letter and single space are allowed and must start with a letter and must have a minimum length of 3

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Following Examples are the outcomes I'm trying to achieve:

```
99Hello -> invalid(starts with numbers)
He  llo -> invalid(has two spaces)
He -> invalid(minimum length 3)
He llo -> valid
He l l o -> valid
Hel -> valid
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{3,}
```

Comment: In what way did this not work?

Comment: Please provide some more information. Thanks

Comment: Try my 2nd example @Nick

Comment: Can there be more than one space as long as they're not adjacent? e.g. is `He l l o` valid?

Comment: `He l l o` valid? yes @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex for your needs:

```
/^(?!.*  )[a-z][a-z ]{2,}/i
```

It has a negative lookahead for 2 spaces next to each other somewhere in the string, then it attempts to match a letter followed by 2 or more letters and/or spaces.

```js
let t = ['99Hello',
'He  llo',
'He',
'He llo',
'He l l o',
'Hel'];

console.log(t.filter(v => /^(?!.*  )[a-z][a-z ]{2,}/i.test(v)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
^[a-zA-Z]((?! {2})[a-zA-z ]){2,}$
```

The start and end delimiters are important. If it is a minimum of three, you need to set the number you are looking for to 2 to take into account the first character that is uncounted in that latter group.

It also uses a negative lookahead which is what the ?! is. This means that if it finds what is comes after the ?! in the match that it is not considered a valid match.

I have used ' {2}' to make it very obvious that I am looking for two spaces as '  ' could be ambiguous down the line.

If you do not already, there are plenty of online resources that allow you to test your regex, as well as be able to look up syntax. I personally use https://regex101.com/.